# FreeRDP / Remmina from Ubuntu to Ubuntu shows black screen except from top menu bar and is not interactable

Tags: ubuntu, rdp, freerdp

I have a setup with a cloud VM connected to a local laptop via VPN, and I want to RDP into this local laptop from the cloud VM.

It connects just fine but is unusable as it only shows a black screen. Once in a while I am able to actually render the background, and a few times I have been able to open an app. The drawing of the screen is however so incredible slow -- line by line -- that is is completely useless for anything.

I have tested with both xFreeRDP and Remmina. I currently use Remmina for the exact same application with RDP to a Raspberry Pi, and this works without any issues.

In Remmina, I have tried all possible settings to optimize network connection, resolutions, color depths and so on. Little does it help.

The other issue I am seeing, is when I close the remote connection, I am unable to open it again before the laptop has been rebooted. I don't know why that is and it is not an issue I see on the Raspberry Pi.

The third issue I have, is that the user on the laptop needs to be logged out. Otherwise the remote connection fails. This is also not what I am seeing on the Raspberry Pi. Here the user is auto logged in, and it does not seem to care.

If someone could help me debug this, it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]